# Alternative ways of combining display:none and display:flex

Tags: jquery, flexbox, toggle, display

I have had a problem with combining `display: none` and `display: flex` . I'm aware there is a lot of questions on this. However, I'd like to share a particular way round this. It doesn't satisfy me completely because the **animations are incompatible** with it. Here's what I did:

- I have one div that I want to be hidden at first and be toggled on click (of another div). So the hidden div (`navigation`) should have a `display: none` at first and then when it is toggled it should have a `display: flex`
- On (`navi`) click, a class is toggled (`shown`) and in the css, shown has the properties `display: flex` and another for space arrangement purposes
- The problem is toggling classes does include adding animations

Here's a minimal example :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".navi").click(function() {
    $(".navi .fa-chevron-down").toggleClass("rotate180");
    $(".navigation").toggleClass("shown")
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  --bg: mistyrose;
  --accent-light: #f67e7d;
  --accent-dark: #A94645;
  --accent-cont: #fff;
  --text: #371C1C;
}

body {
  background: var(--bg);
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: var(--text);
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

/* Navigation */

.navi {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(10px + 7vh);
  left: 7vw;
  width: 14vw;
  min-width: 160px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: var(--accent-light);
  text-align: center;
}

.navi i {
  margin-left: 4.5vw;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.navi .fa-chevron-down {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.rotate180 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.navigation {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(30px + 12vh);
  left: 7vw;
  width: 14vw;
  min-width: 160px;
  height: 24vh;
  min-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: var(--accent-light);
  display: none;
}

.shown {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.navigation span {
  color: var(--accent-cont);
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navigation a:hover i {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  color: var(--accent-cont) !important;
}

.navigation a:hover span {
  color: var(--text);
}

.navigation i {
  display: block;
  color: var(--text) !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0px 10px -10px 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>

  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="navi"> NAVIGATION <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>

  <!--Navigation-->
  <div class="navigation">

    <a href="{text:Link One Url}"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i><span>About</span></a>
    <a href="{text:Link Two Url}"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i><span>Answers</span></a>
    <a href="{text:Link Nine Url}"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i><span>Files</span></a>
    <a href="{text:Link Three Url}"><i class="fa fa-star"></i><span>Favorites</span></a>
    <a href="{text:Link Four Url}"><i class="fa fa-film"></i><span>Movies</span></a>
    <a href="{text:Link Eight Url}"><i class="fa fa-link"></i><span>Links</span></a>
    <a href="{text:Twitter url}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i><span>Twitter</span></a>
    <a href="{text:Instagram url}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i><span>Instagram</span></a>
    <a href="{text:Youtube url}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i><span>Youtube</span></a>

  </div>
  <!--End Navigation-->


</body>
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y1fpvu2d/19/) is a jsfiddle if it's easier.

---

So what I'm asking really is an alternative way round this maybe? I've tried putting the hidden attribute but it didn't have any effect and toggling first and then changing the display from block to flex but it looks wrong with the tiles etc.. If you have another solution, I'd be glad to hear it, thank you!

Comment: https://www.impressivewebs.com/animate-display-block-none/

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?ei=4sw6W9aeO8qy5gL2gbTQCA&q=css+display+none+animation&oq=css+display+none+animation&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71k1l8.0.0.0.43410.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.H3NSX-E2NNw